# Salesforce lightning CLI error no-undef 'sforce' is not defined

Tags: lightning-aura-components

error         no-undef       'sforce' is not defined
  Line:196:13
              sforce.one.back(true);

As a solution I did following checks -

```
if(typeof sforce !== 'undefined') {
  sforce.one.back(true);
}
```

It is still giving me same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error can be solved by Documentation given by ESLint
http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef 
You can add

```
/*global sforce:true*/
if(typeof sforce !== 'undefined') {
  sforce.one.back(true);
}
```

This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The lightning CLI is chatty at this moment and not all of the warnings and errors needs to be resolved .This is definitely a false positive and need not be resolved .

Comment: Is there any way to disable this error as we do in eslint or jshint?

Comment: Yes .You can look here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules_customization.htm