# In salesforce code analyzer I am getting "no-undef" error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, javascript

I tried to solve in this way

```
if(typeof sforce !== 'undefined') 

{  

sforce.one.back(true);

}
```

but its still giving me the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Salesforce lightning CLI error no-undef 'sforce' is not defined](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151458/salesforce-lightning-cli-error-no-undef-sforce-is-not-defined)